# What is shape of Scikit-learn KNeighborsClassfier custom weights?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I wonder what shape of custom weight should be. Below, there is my code using custom weights in KNN. But I encountered this error. I don't know why the error is occuring.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassfier

def custom_dist(train_ftr1, train_ftr2, test_ftr1, test_ftr2):
    return (train_ftr1 - test_ftr1) * (train_ftr2, test_ftr2)

# Split data
X_train = train.drop(['Label'], axis=1)
y_train = train['Label']

X_test = np.array([[test_ftr1, test_ftr2]])

# training model
knn = KNeighborsClassfier(n_neighbors=k, weights=custom_dist)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
y_test_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
```

```
TypeError: custom_dist() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'train_ftr2', 'test_ftr1', and 'test_ftr2'
```